# How to drag an item outside a ListView in QML

Tags: qt, listview, drag-and-drop, qml

I am developing a QML application which basically contains two ListView. I would like to copy a QML item from one ListView to another. I tried to handle this by setting Drag property in the delegate but the item cannot go outside the view when I drag the item, I think the Flickable container handles mouse events.
So, I want to try the following:

- create a mousearea which overlaps the to ListView

  create a new object by calling **createComponent() / createObject()**

  reparent this object to the mousearea

  handle mouse events in the mousearea till drop

This solution seems to me a little complicated, so do you have a better way to achieve this ?

---

This was a bad idea and too much complicated. I think I got a way to achieve this:

- each delegate of the ListView has a hidden Item which can be dragged,

  as my ListView are in a reusable component, I use a property to pass a higher item (a Rectangle here and NOT a **MouseArea**) which can be used as parent for dragged items,

  the higher item contains the two ListView (and maybe more in the future),

  when the drag begins, the item is set to visible and reparented using a **State**

So, I missed the point that set the parent should solve my problem.

Comment: I've been working with some ideas and I've [uploaded](https://github.com/ftena/qt-snippets/tree/master/qml-drag-and-drop-listview-36449029) the code to GitHub. I don't know your list model - in the code uploaded is very simple - and if I've understood the issue right, so I don't want to post this as an answer yet. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, it is close from what I want to achieve but the item is moved instead of copied. I missed the point that dragged item should be reparented to a higher level item. I think I have a solution inspired from your sample @Tarod.

Comment: Great! Please, tell me if you want me to post my code as an answer or you're going to post your own solution. Happy coding!

Comment: Yes, it could be usefull, do you think you can add a comment about the fact the item is moved and not copied ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next code is just an idea, but the key is to have a `MouseArea` inside a `delegate` for the first `ListView` so the user can drag the items and drop them into a `DropArea` which belongs to the second `ListView`.

In this example, `model` is very simple, just a number. And when the item is dropped, it is removed from the first `ListView`:

`listView.model.remove(listView.dragItemIndex)`

Just remove that line of code to copy the item instead of removing.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 600

    Rectangle {
        id: root
        width: 400
        height: 400

        ListView {
            id: listView
            width: parent.width / 2
            height: parent.height

            property int dragItemIndex: -1

            model: ListModel {
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                        append({value: i});
                    }
                }
            }

            delegate: Item {
                id: delegateItem
                width: listView.width
                height: 50

                Rectangle {
                    id: dragRect
                    width: listView.width
                    height: 50
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    color: "salmon"
                    border.color: Qt.darker(color)

                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: modelData
                    }

                    MouseArea {
                        id: mouseArea
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        drag.target: dragRect

                        drag.onActiveChanged: {
                            if (mouseArea.drag.active) {
                                listView.dragItemIndex = index;
                            }
                            dragRect.Drag.drop();
                        }
                    }

                    states: [
                        State {
                            when: dragRect.Drag.active
                            ParentChange {
                                target: dragRect
                                parent: root
                            }

                            AnchorChanges {
                                target: dragRect
                                anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined
                                anchors.verticalCenter: undefined
                            }
                        }
                    ]

                    Drag.active: mouseArea.drag.active
                    Drag.hotSpot.x: dragRect.width / 2
                    Drag.hotSpot.y: dragRect.height / 2
                }
            }
        }

        ListView {
            id: listView2
            width: parent.width / 2
            height: parent.height
            anchors.right: parent.right

            property int dragItemIndex: -1

            DropArea {
                id: dropArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                onDropped: {
                    listView2.model.append(listView.model.get(listView.dragItemIndex))
                    listView.model.remove(listView.dragItemIndex)
                    listView.dragItemIndex = -1;
                }
            }

            model: ListModel {
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    for (var i = 0; i < 1; ++i) {
                        append({value: i});
                    }
                }
            }

            delegate: Item {
                id: delegateItem2
                width: listView2.width
                height: 50

                Rectangle {
                    id: dragRect2
                    width: listView2.width
                    height: 50
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    color: "salmon"
                    border.color: Qt.darker(color)

                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: modelData
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried similarly but my item gets dropped everywhere what i do to limit dropping only to DropArea

Comment: @GeorgeThomas I'd like to see your code in order to help you and test the app.

Comment: i have uploaded a question please check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40085507/view-item-gets-dropped-outside-drop-area-in-qml